# Create a series with the last amount of bars in pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I want to have a series of the latest prices
And I want to add it to a number
I tried every method but I could not. If you know of a method, please introduce it
Thankful

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered. Pls provide more information about the problem you are trying to solve, preferably with code showing your attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi dear friend
I can get the last price using the state.is last bar, but only on the last bar
I want to have the latest price on all bars

Comment: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#what-is-the-variable-name-for-the-current-price